# jQuery Mobile how to set hidePlaceholderMenuItems value

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've got a select item that is populated using json but the jquery mobile select doesnt show the default selected value. I've read the documentation and they say the following needs to be set:

```
$.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.hidePlaceholderMenuItems = false;
```

But I'm really not sure how to do this

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it in mobileinit event before jQuery Mobile is initialized, like this:

```
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script>
        $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
            $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.hidePlaceholderMenuItems = true;
        });        
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
</head>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/VmsRg/